# Dynamic legend with Bokeh - scalling issue

Tags: python, bokeh, databricks, dashboard, interactive

we have developed some interactive dashboard on DataBricks using Bokeh. It works out splendid and provides an easy data exploration for us. However, the ability to use the legend to show and hide graphs have proven to depend on the aspect ratio of the figure as examplefied by the code below. The example is a modification of the source from https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html

Is this a scalling issue in the Bokeh framework? In my test the code works as intended for width=< height.

Thanks for any feedback.

```
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, output_file, show

output_file("toolbar.html")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
    desc=['A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'],
    imgs=[
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake.jpg',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake2.png',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake3D.png',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake4_TheRevenge.png',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snakebite.jpg'
    ],
    fonts=[
        '<i>italics</i>',
        '<pre>pre</pre>',
        '<b>bold</b>',
        '<small>small</small>',
        '<del>del</del>'
    ]
))

TOOLTIPS = """
    <div>
        <div>
            <img
                src="@imgs" height="42" alt="@imgs" width="42"
                style="float: left; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;"
                border="2"
            ></img>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;">@desc</span>
            <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #966;">[$index]</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>@fonts{safe}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 15px;">Location</span>
            <span style="font-size: 10px; color: #696;">($x, $y)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
"""

p = figure(width=600, height=400, tooltips=TOOLTIPS,
           title="Mouse over the dots")

p.circle('x', 'y', size=20, source=source)

show(p)
```

Comment: Your example does not provide a legend. Please edit your example. I tried to create a test with a legend with `p.circle('x', 'y', size=20, source=source, legend_label='A')` and `p.legend.click_policy="hide"` and didn' t see any problems in my jupyter notebook.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.